# Extract full Path and File Name

Tags: python, path, os.walk

Attempting to write a function that walks a file system and returns the absolute path and filename for use in another function.

Example `"/testdir/folderA/222/filename.ext"`.

Having tried multiple versions of this I cannot seem to get it to work properly.

```
filesCheck=[]

def findFiles(filepath):
    files=[]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filepath):
        for file in files:
            currentFile = os.path.realpath(file)
            print (currentFile)
            if os.path.exists(currentFile):
                files.append(currentFile)

    return files

filesCheck = findFiles(/testdir)
```

This returns
`"filename.ext"` (only one).

Substitute in `currentFile = os.path.join(root, file)` for `os.path.realpath(file)` and it goes into a loop in the first directory.   Tried `os.path.join(dir, file)` and it fails as one of my folders is named `222`.

I have gone round in circles and get somewhat close but haven't been able to get it to work.
Running on Linux with Python 3.6

Comment: Why are you testing if a file returned by os.walk actually exists? How could it be returned if it didn't actually exist?

Comment: Could you explain more about how the function goes into a loop when you use os.path.join? That should be the correct solution, but what kind of output are you getting?

Comment: What `files` do you think you are appending to? Note there are a number of things you call `files` and what is happening is likely not what you think. In fact, does your program ever end?

Comment: To be 100% clear, rename `files=[]` to `retval=[]` then append to it and return it not `files` as `files` inside your `for` loop hides the original `files`. With those changes, your program runs fine.

Comment: Responding to Comments

Comment: 1) As the function is not currently returning full file paths I add in a check if exists to keep it from erroring out.
2) From the print (currentFile) statement it prints the half-correct path and the file name of the first sub directory, and then prints them again, not printing all the directories. 
3) As we stripped the code down to the bare bones other than the import OS statement and actual long file structure everything is there in our test code.
4) Tried renaming and still find /“working directory”/filename opposed to /”long file location with several sub directories/filename.ext”

Answer (score 0):

There's a several things wrong with your code.

1. There are multiple values are being assigned to the variable name `files`.
2. You're not adding the `root` directory to each filename `os.walk()` returns which can be done with [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).
3. You're not passing a string to the `findFiles()` function.

If you fix those things there's no longer a need to call `os.path.exists()` because you can be sure it does.

Here's a working version:

```
import os

def findFiles(filepath):
    found = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filepath):
        for file in files:
            currentFile = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root, file))
            found.append(currentFile)

    return found

filesCheck = findFiles('/testdir')
print(filesCheck)
```

Comment: Thank You, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this is what you need. Perhaps you could give it a try :)

```
from os import walk

path = "C:/Users/SK/Desktop/New folder"

files = []
for (directoryPath, directoryNames, allFiles) in walk(path):
    for file in allFiles:
        files.append([file, f"{directoryPath}/{file}"])

print(files)
```

Output:

```
[ ['index.html', 'C:/Users/SK/Desktop/New folder/index.html'], ['test.py', 'C:/Users/SK/Desktop/New folder/test.py'] ]
```